# How to change props dynamically - fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, fullcalendar, react-props

I use the fullcalendar library,
I want to change the calendar language when I change the language of the site.
the default language of the calendar is 'en'.
I want to change the locale but this prop is read only.
The program is written in react-redux.

here the function that create the calendar

```
export const createCalendar = (title) => {
  let id = nextId();
  let calendarRef = React.createRef();
  let calendar = <div className='calendar'>
    <h1 className='calendar-title'>{title}</h1>
    <FullCalendar
      ref={calendarRef}
      id={id}
      defaultView='timeGridWeek'
      plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
      customButtons={{
        save: {
          text: 'Save',
          click: function () {
            alert('clicked the custom button!');
          }
        }
      }}
      header={{
        center: '',
        left: '',
        right: 'save'
      }}
      hiddenDays={[6]}
      allDaySlot={false}
      slotDuration='00:30:00'
      snapDuration='00:05:00'
      minTime="07:00:00"
      maxTime="23:00:00"
      height="auto"
      titleFormat={{ weekday: 'long' }}
      columnHeaderFormat={{ weekday: 'long' }}
      selectable={true}
      selectHelper={true}
      editable={true}
      droppable={true}
      eventDrop={function (info) { eventChanged(info, id); }}
      eventReceive={function (info) { addEvent(info, id); forceSchedsUpdate(id); }}
      eventResize={function (info) { eventChanged(info, id); }}
      eventLimit={true}
      eventClick={eventClick}
      events={[]}
      locales={allLocales}
      locale={store.getState().literals.lang}
      dir={store.getState().literals.dir} />
  </div>
  store.dispatch({
    type: CREATE_CALENDAR,
    payload: { calendar, title, id, calendarRef }
  });
}
```

here the reducer of the calendars

```
import { GET_SCHEDULES, SET_LOADING, SCHEDULE_ERROR, CREATE_CALENDAR, SELECT_CALENDAR, DELETE_SCHEDULE, ADD_EVENT, DELETE_EVENT, EVENT_CHANGED, CHANGE_LANG_SCHEDS } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
  schedules: {},
  counter: 0,
  current: null,
  loading: false,
  error: null
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_SCHEDULES:
      return {
        ...state,
        schedules: action.payload,
        loading: false
      };
    case CREATE_CALENDAR:
      return {
        ...state,
        current: action.payload.id,
        schedules: { ...state.schedules, [action.payload.id]: action.payload }
      }
    case SELECT_CALENDAR:
      return {
        ...state,
        current: action.payload
      }
    case DELETE_SCHEDULE:
      delete state.schedules[action.payload]
      return {
        ...state,
        counter: state.counter + 1
      }
    case ADD_EVENT:
      state.schedules[action.payload.schedId].calendarRef.current.props.events.push(action.payload.event);
      return {
        ...state
      }
    case EVENT_CHANGED:
      state.schedules[action.payload.schedId].calendarRef.current.props.events.forEach(event => {
        if (event.eventId === action.payload.eventId) {
          event.endTime = action.payload.endTime;
          event.startTime = action.payload.startTime;
          event.daysOfWeek[0] = action.payload.daysOfWeek;
        }
      });
      return {
        ...state
      }
    case DELETE_EVENT:
      const copySchedsDeleteEvent = state.schedules;
      copySchedsDeleteEvent[action.payload.sched_id].calendarRef.current.props.events.pop(action.payload.event_id);
      return {
        ...state,
        schedules: copySchedsDeleteEvent
      }
    case SET_LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      };
    case SCHEDULE_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: action.payload
      };
    case CHANGE_LANG_SCHEDS:
      for (let key in state.schedules) {//not working 
        //state.schedules[key].calendarRef.current.setOption('locale', 'en');
        //state.schedules[key].calendarRef.current.props.dir = action.payload.dir;
      }
      return {
        ...state,
        counter: state.counter + 1
      };
    default:
      return { ...state };
  }
}
```

Comment: please edit your post and share some code and effort that you tried. in this way, peoples can help you more accurately.

Comment: There is a demo showing how to change the fullCalendar locale here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/locale-demo . It is linked from the [locale documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/localization). And if you click the "Edit in Codepen" link in the top right corner of that page it will show you the source code for it. I'm sure you can adapt that to fit into your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to load ALL locales have the ability to switch between them after pageload, do something like this:

```
import { Calendar } from 
'@fullcalendar/core';
import allLocales from 
'@fullcalendar/core/locales-all';
```

...

```
 let calendar = new 
Calendar(calendarEl, {
locales: allLocales,
locale: 'fr' // the initial locale
});
```

and in your user-end JavaScript use

```
 calendar.setOption('locale', 'pt- 
 br');
```

To set locale dynamically

Comment: I tried to do this, but I don't have access to a function called setOption.
I have added the relevant code

Comment: @ירדןנרקיסי You said "I don't have access to a function called setOption"... I see you're using React. In the documentation for the React component at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/react it tells you how to get access to it in the context of React. Read the section titled "Accessing fullCalendar's API" on that page.